# using delegate for image in qtableview pyqt4 python?

Tags: python, delegates, pyqt4, qtableview

This code will only show same image in the same row. How can i pass different path for image in ImageDelegate? Thanks

```
class testQT4(QtGui.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QTableView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, ImageDelegate(parent))


        #table header
        header = [ 'ID','image']
        tabledata = [[1,2],[3,4]]
        #create table model
        self.model = MyTableModel(tabledata, header, self)
        #set table model
        self.setModel(self.model)


class ImageDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        print dir(self)
        QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):        

        painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QColor(191,222,185))

        # path = "path\to\my\image.jpg"
        self.path = "image.bmp"

        image = QtGui.QImage(str(self.path))
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        pixmap.scaled(50, 40, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        painter.drawPixmap(option.rect, pixmap)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the paint method of the delegate you have access to the model via `index.model()`. You could then query your model for the data (image) you want to show. For example by using the Qt.UserRole for the `data` function of the model.

Another solution, which might even be easier, is that the data function of the model can return one of QIcon, QPixmap, QImage and QColor for the Qt.DecorationRole. In this case no Delegate is necessary.

As an example the following code will put in Icon in the (only) field of the table:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import PyQt4.uic

# using QtDesigner to just put a TableView in a Widget 
Form, Base = PyQt4.uic.loadUiType(r'TableView.ui')

class TableModel( QtCore.QAbstractTableModel ):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TableModel,self).__init__(parent)

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): 
        return 1

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): 
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role): 
        if index.isValid():
            if role==QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole:
                return QtGui.QIcon("ChipScope.png")
        return None


class TableViewUi(Form, Base ):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Form.__init__(self)
        Base.__init__(self,parent)

    def setupUi(self, parent):
        Form.setupUi(self,parent)
        model = TableModel()
        self.tableView.setModel(model)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = TableViewUi()
    ui.setupUi(ui)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(ui)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```